# How to get Type Partial without undefined on this case

Tags: typescript

I get error when i try call method

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

```
Partial<Pac & PacAdmin & PlayerParent>
```

```
class Pac {
    getApi(role?: Role): Partial<Pac & PacAdmin & PlayerParent> {
            const apiProvider = {
                [Role.PacAdmin]: {
                    ...this,
                    ...new PacAdmin()
                },
                [Role.PlayerParent]: {
                    ...this,
                    ...new PlayerParent()
                }             
            }
    
            if (role && apiProvider[role]) {
                return apiProvider[role];
            }
    
            return this;
        }
    }
```

And class PacAdmin

```
class PacAdmin{
someMethod = ()=>{}
}
```

example:

const obj = new Pac();

obj.getApi(Role.PacAdmin).someMethod() - Error here

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwEoQDbDgbwCg4S4AFAQwGMBBAE1QEtE4BeOAIgwHkAZAUQD6ZGgGFBNACIBZAJIA5DgBpScYqTLYKAT2BRKUJPHZc+QsrxoBNfhmE0M-eQBUOhAL6FCVLQGdf5NT0TCz4aqq+EKjA0sAwABYQdGxwABQAlGwAfARwnp7efgGaOnoGRrleBT4U-oFUBOokAOZxNGCMqVA4wAD8AFyYPemDBjCMFNgAPJQNAGT1wcxwCyW6+hSGiDA5RKr7pFQQiL7wFB1k3QBujHR6KXsHTyQA2li4AHSzS4gAuoOPZ5AuAfUEJRi+JRNYFPUEfRDAADuiwYzAy0JheShmNUbx6Xy063K23+jRxsLB8Qh2PJ+zhCORazKmyM6NpeRxGKenlUXIOjAAZmlurgVgtzoxLhAbncoC8RcBfplATjDDBkFAWBKpTK9PKer8ANx8-Y80gm1RqjUscG+Y3PfJeI4neAQABGACsUgz6hlDbz3R6Pq0YO1Ou9gF8gqjEOkPpForEEkk-UA)

Comment: Can you add enough for `Pac`, `PacAdmin`, `PlayerParent`, and `Role` for your sample code to work (excepting the `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` error, naturally)?  It's difficult to debug what's going wrong without [a minimal reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you mean to do `role.PacAdmin` instead of `Role.PacAdmin`? And can you please provide the typings and what method isn't working?

Comment: @KevinMontrose i added more description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the current implementation is that TypeScript has no way to know which attributes of `Pac`, `PacAdmin` or `PlayerParent` will be present in the returned object.

You can specify multiple overload signatures for the `getApi` method, so that the compiler will know the exact type of the returned value depending on the `role` parameter:

```
    getApi(role: Role.PacAdmin): Pac & PacAdmin
    getApi(role: Role.PlayerParent): Pac & PlayerParent
    getApi(role: undefined): Pac
```

See the [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwEoQDbDgbwCg4S4AFAQwGMBBAE1QEtE4BeOAIgwHkAZAUQD6ZGgGFBNACIBZAJIA5DgBpScYqTLYKAT2BRKUJPHZc+QsrxoBNfhmE0M-eQBUOhAL6FCVLQGdf5NT0TCz4aqq+EKjA0sAwABYQdGxwABQAlGwAfARwnp7efgGaOnoGRrleBT4U-oFUBOokAOZxNGCMqVA4wABcmD0AdJS0DMzp-SNwAGT1wcxNcK0w7Z3duP1YuMNauvoUhogwE-Uz5LtlB0aLy6tdPf3IiHTAAGbMwHQnI16qtx33XAAfk2PW+BxgjAo2AAPFNZiN5iwERd9ocYDkiKpsaQqBBEL54BQOmRugA3RgvKApLE4ukkADaW2AwyCY0QAF1+rT6by4IMBQlGL4lIs+TiBYNEMAAO5zdkZMXi9yi8XYplDEp7cpHLmNNX0yVCkVKg38gXSuVay7oxVmkjuA2m7GeVTO1SMV5pdZ4aazYmMUkQClUhk+jmZHkGwwwZBQFgBoMhvRhnocgDc7tIrtIWZIMbjLGNmfp+S8eIJ8AgACMAFYpS31DLpt012uDf6dZms0YhdKDSLRWIJJLNoA).